# Spark Exception : Task failed while writing rows

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am reading text files and converting them to parquet files. I am doing it using spark code. But when i try to run the code I get following exception

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, XXXX.XXX.XXX.local): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$writeRows$1(commands.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.initStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:101)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.<init>(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:94)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.<init>(ParquetRecordWriter.java:64)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:282)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(newParquet.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$$anon$4.newInstance(newParquet.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DefaultWriterContainer.initWriters(commands.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.BaseWriterContainer.executorSideSetup(commands.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$writeRows$1(commands.scala:172)
    ... 8 more
```

I am trying to write the dataframe in following fashion :

```
dataframe.write().parquet(Path)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, yes - I remember running into this. Am trying to think of what the problem was... Which version of Spark? How many partitions do you have? Are you running on AWS EMR and is `Path` by any chance "s3n://..."?

Comment: Spark version is 1.4.1. I am running this on normal 5 node hadoop cluster.    Path is also normal hdfs path.

Comment: can you try to perform an action on the `dataframe` that you want to write into parquet ? (e.g `count`) There is an explainable division by zero somewhere that we need to isolate !

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the `ArithmeticException` (thanks for the reformatting @eliasah :)). In that case, it's not a familiar problem to me, and I agree with @eliasah's comment.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt i have developed a pattern recognition in my eyes.  Reformatting helps too ! :))

Comment: Actually I am not using any division logic in my code. I dont know from where it is coming. Any other solution?

Comment: Hi Guys, Any help?

Comment: Its not just division logic some thing like toInt() or anything Exception will lead the this error. Could you post the code how you created dataframe?

Comment: The problem was parquet schema was not getting generated. so spark tries to find the some statistics from parquet schema and also tries to divide by count or something where this fails as it gets zero as the value.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible reason is that you're hitting s3 request rate limits.  If you look closely at your logs you may see something like this

`AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate.`

While the Spark UI will say

`Task failed while writing rows`

I doubt its the reason you're getting an issue, but its a possible reason if you're running a highly intensive job.  So I included just for answer's completeness.

Comment: I rewrote the code to hit s3 less unfortunately.  Not a scalable solution...  it maybe you can request that limit be increased?

Answer (score 2):

I found that **disabling speculation** prevents this error from happening. I'm not very sure why. It seems that speculative and non-speculative tasks are conflicting when writing parquet rows.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.speculation","false")
```

Comment: It was not a problem of speculation execution. It was a problem of schema not generating correctly and hence / by Zero

Comment: Not a Spark >= 3.1 solution

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I saw this error when I tried to overwrite hdfs directory which belonged to a different user. Deleting the directory a letting my process write it from scratch solved it. So I guess, more digging is appropriate in direction of user permissions on hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

This is where having all the source to hand helps: paste the stack trace in an IDE that can go from stack trace to lines of code, and see what it says. It's probably just some init/config problem

Answer (score 0):

If ever it is still relavant, the experience I had with this issue was that I did not start hadoop. If you run spark on top of it, it might be worth starting hadoop and check again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case below command solve the issue because of values in date column or timestamp column (noticed date out of range for example 1700-01-01 for date column)

```
#Set the spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite property
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
```