# Trying to write dataframe to file, getting org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame called pres2 (about 1000 lines long, generated on an AWS 3-node EMR cluster (v5.3.1) running Spark 2.1.0) which looks like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
|          CreatedAt|               tweet|prediction|
+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
|2015-10-12 20:58:52|This Saturday is ...|       1.0|
|2015-10-13 17:28:45|Sleep with a spoo...|       1.0|
```

(etc.)

I am trying to write said dataframe to a .csv file and I keep getting errors similar to described (but not resolved) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034928/spark-exception-task-failed-while-writing-rows).  I have tried writing this data frame in many different ways and I still get the error shown below.  These methods include:

```
pres2.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("someFile.csv")
pres2.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("someFile.csv")
pres2.write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("someFile.csv")
```

In addition to trying to save it with that basic method to HDFS, I have also tried hdfs://[hostname]/[path] to no avail, although I can see a file of 0 bytes in HDFS.  I also have tried to save to an S3 bucket, which similarly didn't work.

I can only conclude that I just have something screwed up with my cluster, but I have repeated this on other, similar clusters and with the new EMR v5.4.0.  Is there anything that I have done obviously wrong based on the errors below (generated for the first write method shown above, but they all look pretty similar)?

```
17/03/10 16:24:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 149, ip-addy .ec2.internal, executor 9): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$2: (string) => array<string>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:140)
        ... 16 more

17/03/10 16:24:03 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/03/10 16:24:03 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 23.0 (TID 152, ip-addy, executor 9): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$2: (string) => array<string>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:140)
        ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:80)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:85)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:87)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:89)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:91)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:93)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:95)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:97)
        at $line94.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:99)
        at $line94.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:101)
        at $line94.$read.<init>(<console>:103)
        at $line94.$read$.<init>(<console>:107)
        at $line94.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line94.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line94.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line94.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$2: (string) => array<string>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:140)
        ... 16 more
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
  ... 50 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 23.0 (TID 152, ip-addy, executor 9): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$2: (string) => array<string>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:140)
        ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
  ... 69 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$2: (string) => array<string>)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:243)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
  ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:142)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$2.apply(Tokenizer.scala:140)
  ... 16 more
```

Incidently, I did try to convert the dataframe to an RDD and save it as a text file, but that generated its own erros (I exceed the 30000 char limit if I post it here).

Comment: You should also be aware that the "tweet" column is a text data which can have "commas" sometimes. It will a best practice to enclose the text with quotes to avoid data issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have tried 3 different approaches to save the data, but unfortunately they all are the same, only difference is how to write the file, i.e, create new one, overwrite the existing or to write it in append mode,

I would suggest to perform a short experiment by creating schema file and then by using databrick csv to read the file with schema, then print the data schema using,

```
df.printSchema()
```

This will help you understand the datatype of you column, also try to perform it on subset of the original dataset, if that saving, then try to get some analysis on you input data to get more insight what data you are processing.

Comment: This seems to be helping narrow it down.  When I created a dataframe manually, I did not use a header and allowed Spark to infer the schema.  When it did so, it correctly inferred that the first column was a datetime.  However, I note that when I had the header, that column was listed as a string.  But if my datetimes are cast as strings, would that prevent it from writing out?

Comment: ok, that's good, also one more thing, define your schema with StructType in a variable and while reading use `df.schema(dfSchema)`, which will help you to correctly identify your datetime column and probably also will help you in writing the data to output file. To define the schema follow this link:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#scala-api

Comment: This did it!  Something about the strings of datetimes were messing it up.  However, I cast those to epoch time in my data cleaning step in advance (thus being read as a bigint), which is really what I wanted eventually anyway, and was able to write the dataframe in the normal way.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Adding on top of Uday Shankar Singh, whose comments actually helped me to solve the issue.

Check the dataframe schema with `df.printSchema()`. In my case, one of the column was not `nullable`, but I was passing a null value.

Modifying the schema to accept `null` values, actually resolved this issue. Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 3):

The secret in Java and Scala code is always go to the most nested stack  in the stack trace, usually the one where half the stack is missing, and assume that's the cause.

Here the NullPointerException at the bottom is the warning sign. If you have are trying to do some transformation with a regular expression declaring how to spliit up the line, there's probably something wrong there.

I don't think it's the output itself, it's the work generating the output which is failing. Remember: Spark is "lazy", it doesn't do any work until you try to save the RDD.